# Allow remote MySQL access on Linux (through Webmin or shell)

Tags: database, remote-access, remote-debugging, remote-server, webmin

**Spec:**
Ubuntu 14.04
Webmin/Virtualmin 1.791

I am using following code to test remote MySQL database connection:

```
<?php

$db_host = "123.456.789";
$db_name = "database";
$db_user = "user";
$db_pass = "password";
$db_table_prefix = "prefix_";



GLOBAL $errors;
GLOBAL $successes;

$errors = array();
$successes = array();

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
GLOBAL $mysqli;

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Conn Error = " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

?>
```

I keep getting this error:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it.

Research shows this means the server is "not listening". Before I ran the above script I've already tried to allow remote mysql access through webmin gui. What I did is editting "database manage->host permissions" and make it as follows:

[image]

This was supposed to allow remote MySQL access but it doesn't work. Also I read from somewhere else that to allow remote MySQL access I need to edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`; I have thought that after I edit the "host permissions" in Webmin this file would be changed, but it was not. On the other hand, I couldn't find the lines I was supposed to edit in `my.cnf`.

Comment: Refer here : http://www.preprogrammer.com/allow-remote-connections-to-mysql-server-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via **webmin** too,

Create your user account for remote access

- Webmin > Servers > MySQL Database Server > User permissions

[image: Click User Permissions]

Allow the MySQL server to listen to remote requests

- Webmin > Servers > MySQL Database Server > MySQL Server Configuration

[image: MySQL Conf]

MySQL server listening address - set it to any

[image: any]

Restart MySQL using `service mysql restart` or directly from webmin.

Allowing MySQL to listen to any port is not a *good idea* , unless you are the only one who can access that network ,

Don't leave it like **this afterwards** , Its better to Allow certain hosts on certain domains , like your ***IP*** , Or simply just dont listen on all ports if its not required i.e when you are finished with your session.

You can also do this via `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
Just add a `binding adress` of your choice instead of **localhost**

Answer (score 1):

I have got it to work, however not through webmin at all.

First I need to comment out the following line in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
```

I guess instead of simply commenting it out, I can also change `127.0.0.1` to my local IP address. Many google results stop here, but this is not enough. **The next step** is to grant the **local** user privileges: On remote server, I need to run the following commands:

> $ mysql -u root -p 
>   Enter password:
>
> mysql> use mysql
>
> mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'localIP' IDENTIFIED BY
>   'password';
>
> mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Actually I have seen this when I was doing google search before I asked the question here, but I just ignored it because I thought I've done it. It turns out I not only need to grant privileges on server side but also need to do it  for "**local user**".

Feel free to comment here if there's still something I missed out or you know how to do it throught webmin(I am still wondering what editting "host permissions" in webmin does).